# Blank pages when rendering pdf documents with pdf.js

Tags: javascript, ios, pdf, optimization, pdf.js

> I have a two page pdf document that does not render on either Safari
>   or Chrome on iOS, using pdf.js; there are two pages, but they both are
>   blank.  If I "print" the document with CutePDF to another pdf, it
>   renders!  But if I optimize using Acrobat PRO, it does not render.  I
>   read somewhere that if I render as Postscript with Acrobat PRO, and
>   then resave as pdf, that linearizes; still no love.  I show all four
>   flavors [here][1] - the thumbnail shows the pdf metadata, along with
>   the file size.  Only the CutePDF version renders, even though it is
>   not the smallest.  Apart from simply reprinting every pdf I have on my
>   website with CutePDF - can someone tell me what pdf.js is unhappy
>   about?
>
> N.B.:  All four flavors render under Windows.  It's only iOS that has
>   the problem, with three of the four.
>
> [1]: http://59plymouth.net/lightbox/pdfjs.html

Per mkl's suggestion, I'm editing my post.

I've since revised the example above, to include just the two pdfs:  The one that doesn't render in iOS browsers when you click the thumbnail (on the left), and the one on the right that does - the original, reprinted with CutePDF.

My issue got tagged over on github, and it's still open as an issue - but, that's the extent of it. Trying to use the pdf.js debugging tools reads like stereo instructions to me, and I don't believe they work on iOS anyway. The Chrome Developer Tools don't; the best I can do is chrome://inspect, but that doesn't register a complaint. I really don't know what else to do. Any other takers?

Comment: Please share the pdf in question for analysis.

Comment: There are *four* pdfs in question - all of which can be downloaded from the page in the link.

Comment: Ah, at first glance I thought those were merely screen shots...

Comment: All the non-working versions have the bitmap drawn as a single large XObject wrapped in a pattern. The working version has the bitmap cut into many smaller images drawn directly in the page content. You may want to look for pdf.js issues related to those factors.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful!  I'll investigate further, but may be back with more questions.  Thanks again!

Comment: There's a similar complaint over on github for pdfjs; I added this thread there:  https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9570  But so far, no takers.  Assuming that avoiding large bitmaps in XObjects is the solution, I don't have a clue as to how to avoid them.  Printing things with CutePDF can have adverse effects, based on the source pdf - rotation, cropping, etc.  Is there a way to produce a pdf with Acrobat that specify ID commands instead of DO commands (if I understand the difference)?

Comment: That would be inline images, a technique that should be used only for small images, not more that a few KB.

Comment: You had said, "The working version has the bitmap cut into many smaller images drawn directly in the page content."  Is that the technique, then?  pdf.js was happy on iOS with the pdf rendered by CutePDF.  But I'm not aware of any pdf producer that permits you to control how it's done; CutePDF bakes it into the cake, apparently.  But it also does bad things for other pdfs.

Comment: The smaller images in the CutePDF output are not inlined, they also are drawn using **Do** from the page resources.

Comment: Interesting...  Thanks for your help.  I've slimmed down the example, and posted over on github:  https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/11571

Comment: Over on github, someone suggested "Please note that it's much more likely to be a <canvas> size limitation of the iOS platform itself, rather than a PDF.js library bug per se".  pdf.js must take some attributes from the pdf, and recommend a canvas based on that.  What would those attributes be - and, can they be constrained during pdf production?

Comment: I hardly know anything about those pdf.js, js, and platform details.

Comment: My issue got tagged over on github, and it's still open as an issue - but, that's the extent of it.  Trying to use the pdf.js debugging tools reads like stereo instructions to me, and I don't know if they work on iOS anyway.  The Chrome Developer Tools don't; the best I can do is chrome://inspect, but that doesn't register a complaint.  I really don't know what else to do.  Any other takers?

Comment: You should [edit] that into your question instead of writing it as a comments. Only the previous commenter is informed about a new comment but after an edit the question gets more prominent universally.

Comment: No takers; (*sigh*)...  I guess I have to dig in and acquaint myself with PDF.  Can you recommend a good object browser?  Sorry to ask here, I don't see a way to contact you through SO (except for the email address you recommend folks not use)

Comment: I usually use the iText RUPS or the PDFBox PDFDebugger. Adobe Acrobat Preflight also contains a pdf object browser.